# Stanford parser - typed dependencies

Tags: java, parsing, stanford-nlp

I need to handle with possessive dependencies in stanford parser.I read in a mailing list that to use the output format

```
includePunctuationDependencies
```

but I get this exception. Can anyone please give me link to the Stanford parser that supports this output format?

I'm currently using the Stanford parser version 9-07-2010.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error: output tree format includePunctuationDependencies not supported
        at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreePrint.<init>(TreePrint.java:134)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreePrint.<init>(TreePrint.java:101)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreePrint.<init>(TreePrint.java:89)
        at finalproj.logic.parser.SentenceSplitterTagger.getTypedDependenciesSentence(SentenceSplitterTagger.java:82)
        at finalproj.logic.parser.SentenceSplitterTagger.splitFile(SentenceSplitterTagger.java:36)
        at finalproj.ui.LoadReqFile.jBtnSentenceSplitActionPerformed(LoadReqFile.java:143)
        at finalproj.ui.LoadReqFile.access$200(LoadReqFile.java:23)
        at finalproj.ui.LoadReqFile$3.actionPerformed(LoadReqFile.java:74)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6267)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6032)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get a better/quicker response from their mail list: parser-user@lists.stanford.edu.

You can search their [mail list archive](https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/parser-user/) as well.